# A warning statement appears when I run React

Tags: node.js, reactjs

A warning statement appears when you run React.

please help me.

```
(node:17128) [DEP0148] DeprecationWarning: Use of deprecated folder mapping "./" in the "exports" field module resolution of the package at 
C:\Users\adqwe\Desktop\dsad\dev\peonani-web\node_modules\postcss-js\package.json.


Update this package.json to use a subpath pattern like "./*".
(Use `node --trace-deprecation ...` to show where the warning was created)
```

Comment: See if they've updated that module to address the deprecation?

Comment: Thank you.
I downgraded postcss version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

postcss version downgraded

"postcss": "^8.3.6", -> "postcss":  "^8.2.12"

Comment: You should upgrade to 8.2.13 now if possible because of a vulnerability in postcss that was patched in that version.

Comment: @Suzana You're right.